# Get the git fetch output string in text file

Tags: windows, text, cmd, git-fetch

I am trying to get the output string of the `Git fetch` command in a text file. The data Which I need is the size of the gitlab project.

[image]

```
  git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch -v>test.txt 2>&1
```

After I run the above code there is some data in the `test.txt` file which contain `POST git-upload-pack (675 bytes)`. But I don`t need that data. I need the the full size of the project which I shown in the image. The data which I need is exist in the below command.

```
git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch -v >test.txt
```

My problem is, If I run the above command means I got nothing in the `test.txt` file. But the data which I need is displaying in the `cmd` window. How would I get the data in text file?

Comment: `for /F "tokens=5-6" %%K in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:"') do echo %%K %%L`

Comment: @aschipfl How can I run this cmd in windows? I got the exception `%%K was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Ah, in command prompt (`cmd`), you need to state `%K` and `%L` instead of `%%K` and `%%L`; type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help...

Comment: @aschipfl I can run this command. But I do not understand this command working. That means how can I get the Receiving objects line? Either I need to get it in text file or get the line in as a string in c#code? I tried this 
`git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.syncfusion.com/testgroup/server-base-encryption.git & for /F "tokens=5-6" %K in ('git fetch -v 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:"') do echo %K %L` I  did not get the text file.

Comment: How can I get the particular line as a string? I tried the same command line in c# coding but I get  " " in the coding!

Comment: I don't know which of your commands actually produce the output text you show in your question; perhaps you may have to include all `git` command into the `for /F` loop, like this: `for /F "tokens=5-6" %K in ('git init ^& git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git ^& git fetch -v 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /B /C:"Receiving objects:"') do echo %K %L`

Comment: If you insist on using an interim text file, try this: `(git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch -v) > test.txt`, then read it by `for /F "tokens=5-6" %K in (test.txt) do echo %K %L`

Comment: @aschipfl when I run the second command I get the below text only in my text file. But I get the fetching details in cmd window. `Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/path.git/`

Comment: @aschipfl If I run this `git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & (git fetch -v > test.txt)` command means I got empty text file.

Comment: What about this: `(git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch -v) > test.txt 2>&1` (this also redirects _STDERR_ to the file, perhaps the data you need is output there rather than at _STDOUT_; if you use this within a `for /F` loop like I showed in previous comments, you need to change it to `2^>^&1`)

Comment: @aschipfl By using this command `(git init & git remote add origin https://gitlab.company.com/project.git & git fetch -v) > test.txt 2>&` I get the branch details of this! I did not get the output like the image shown in the question.

Comment: First, you need to find out which of the `git` commands produces the output (call one after another, then try to redirect each one into the text file, with and without `2>&!`); then you can build the correct `for /F` loop to extract the desired data...

Comment: @aschipfl I tried step by step. But I did not get the `git fetch` output in the text file. I tried by both `git fetch >text.txt` and `git fetch >text.txt 2>&1` I get the branch details while running the second command `git fetch >text.txt 2>&1` If I run `git fetch` alone I can get the output in the expected output in the cmd screen